# The navbar dropdown menu does not beyond the container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here is the navbar html

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <nav class="navbar" id="nav_menu">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown item open">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About us</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="">People</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

And the problem is the size is restrict to the navbar height, that means the dropdown box can not go beyond the nav bar size. I suspect it is not caused by z-index after checking. It is something related to the overflow, but any element tag need to change?

Thanks for helping

**The test link:**
http://kotechweb.com/kmk/

Comment: can you share the code in jsfiddle?

Comment: check z-index of side menu

Comment: Please share codes or link of following site.

Comment: sure ,wait 3 minute,

Comment: added the site, please take a look, thanks

Comment: `.row `(parents of `navbar`) element has `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: What @Alex said...

Comment: Add these rule to your css `.navbar-nav > li:hover ul { display: block;}` and `header .row:nth-child(2) { overflow: visible;}`

Comment: It's as mentioned before. When the `top` property of the absolute positioned dropdown menu gets higher, it gets pushed further down on the screen. As the `.row` div has an `overflow:hidden`, the dropdown menu will be cut off at the end of the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<div class="row" style="overflow:visible;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

get rid of

```
.left_menu_body {
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

really don't understand why you did that crazy "hack" on `.left_menu_body`

Comment: because the left side col need to same height as right side

Comment: ..and this is the worst way to do it