# How to show navbar dropdown menu outside container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, overflow

So before this problem, I was struggling to make the navbar scroll on smaller screens when expanded. SO link: [responsive fixed-top navbar when expanded fills up screen, hides some of the nav-links, and does not scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713344/responsive-fixed-top-navbar-when-expanded-fills-up-screen-hides-some-of-the-nav)

Using the answer in that question, I was able to make the navbar scroll but I was then faced with a new issue. When clicked on the navbar link, the dropdown menu that popped up would stay within the navbar container, and the navbar could be scrolled.

A picture to explain **(OLE dropdown in this case)**:
[image]

This is the CSS used to make the collapsed navbar scrollable.

```
.fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 4.5em);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

There is no problem when navbar collapsed and it can show the dropdown menu fine and scroll. But, when not collapsed on larger screen, how do i make the dropdown menu show outside the navbar container?

Here's my JSFiddle for this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/suhaib47/7b58o0d3/3/

Note: make the result viewport wide enough that navbar can be fully displayed. Click on the OLE dropdown, and you will have to scroll down to see the dropdown menu.

---

When I show the dropdown menu outside the container, the menu cannot be scrolled on smaller screens. When the menu CAN be scrolled, I cannot get the dropdown menu to show outside the nav container.

How do I make the dropdown menu show outside the navbar container? At the same time I'd like the responsive navbar to be scrollable when expanded on smaller screens.

I found a similar SO question but could not get it to fix my problem: [The navbar dropdown menu does not beyond the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775117/the-navbar-dropdown-menu-does-not-beyond-the-container)

Comment: Can you include your code please?

Comment: @Gerard I've added some css code and a JSFiddle link

Comment: This seems to work fine in jsfiddle

Comment: ajust the width of the result window so that the "hamburger" toggle icon is no longer displayed, and the navbar can be seen with its links. click on the OLE link and you will see that the dropdown menu does not pop out, instead it stays within the container and you end up scrolling within the navbar to see it.

Comment: The overflow-y is causing the issue. You should put that into a media query.

Comment: I need that because on mobile screens, the expanded navbar menu takes up more than the device height, and some menu items cannot be accessed. overflow-y can ensure that the user can scroll down the navbar menu. I have included the link to the SO question from where i got the answer to use overflow in the beginning of this question.

Comment: You should put that into a media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoped there would be a solution to this without having to use media queries. Nevertheless, I was indeed able to fix this using media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: calc(100vh - 4.5em);
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```

This way scrolling is available when needed, depending on the display size/orientation, i.e. when the navbar menu is collapsed.